# How to get all documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
    void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState



    super.initState();
    getusers().then((dataf){
snapshots=dataf.documents[1];// In here 
    });
  }
final db=Firestore.instance;
DocumentSnapshot snapshots;

Future<QuerySnapshot> getusers(){
 return  db.collection("Users").document(widget.userid).collection("UsersJoined").getDocuments();
}
```

I want to get all the documents and fields inside documents without referring to their index. Is it possible by a loop or something to loop through the whole documents and get all their fields

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate the elements of the array `dataf.documents`?

Comment: yeah something like that , But I figured it out thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`:

```
getusers().then((dataf){
  for (var userDoc in dataf.documents) {
    print(userDoc["name"] // get the value of one field
    var data = userDoc.data // get all data as a Map<String, Object>
  })
});
```